# Web Application can't displaying Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, host-header

i have encountered a really strange issue. i have created a new web application and site collection with a custom host header (intranet.contoso.ulo).

i  followed the steps outline by this guide: http://thuansoldier.net/?p=1323

1. Disabled loop back checking
2. Added to the host file
3. Add entry to dns
4. Configure host header for a Web application in IIS under Edit Site Bindings
5. Configure alternate access mappings
6. Restarted IIS
7. flush dns
8. ping the site using command prompt with the host header intranet.contoso.ulo  and get a response

i was only enable to access the site if i click on the central admin icon in my sharepoint windows 2012 server and then open a new tab to access the site. if i open a new IE and try to access the site, i will get a page can't be displayed. the web application is created on port 80. is it a problem with the port?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the site after clicking on "Central Administration" link, it means it is running under elevated privilege. As it runs as an administrator. Could you please confirm that the user account with which you are trying to access the site is site collection administrator?

Comment: yeah. you are right. i was able to hit the site if i open IE as an administrator. if i don't, it will simply show me a 'this page can't be displayed message'. will this happen to other user (which are not administrator) accessing this site collection from their machine?